# Output Line Adding Numbers Onto User Input (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Ever since I added text into my output, it keeps adding numbers onto the `inputTemperature`. For example, if the user enters "**10**", the output line will say: "**-112** degrees Celsius converts to..." And the conversion will be correct. Do you have any ideas as to what may be causing this to happen?

```
// VARIABLES
double inputTemperature;  // Stores user input
double celsius;  // Celsius value
double fahrenheit;  // Farhenheit value

// INPUT
if (double.TryParse(txtTemperature.Text, out inputTemperature) == false)  // Checking that user input is valid
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");  // Error message that is displayed
    txtTemperature.ResetText();  // Resets the form
    txtTemperature.Focus();  // Places the user's cursor back in the Temperature textbox
}

// PROCESSING
if (optCelsius.Checked)  // If the celsius button is clicked, then the temperature needs to be converted from fahrenheit
{
    fahrenheit = double.Parse(txtTemperature.Text);
    fahrenheit = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    lblNewTemperature.Text = fahrenheit.ToString(inputTemperature + " degrees Celsius converts to " + fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit.");
}
else if (optFahrenheit.Checked)  // If the fahrenheit button is clicked, then the temperature needs to be converted from celsius
{
    celsius = double.Parse(txtTemperature.Text);
    celsius = ((celsius * 9) / 5 + 32);
    lblNewTemperature.Text = celsius.ToString(inputTemperature + " degrees Fahrenheit converts to " + celsius + " degrees Celsius.");
}
```

Comment: There is quite a bit of weirdness to your code.  Why are your Celsius and Fahrenheit variables declared so early?  Why do you parse the textbox text 3 times?

Comment: If I take the parses on the textboxes out, I get an error on both `celsius` and `fahrenheit`. Which I'm also not sure why is happening...

Comment: I think he means that you only need to parse it once in the first `if`, because if that's successful you then have the result saved in `inputTemperature`, which you can use in your other `if` and `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a lot of weirdness with your code, but it looks like your issue comes down to two problems.

First you are doing the math wrong.  You are performing *integer* division which is causing some data loss.  Try your calculations like this:

```
//Convert Celsius To Fahrenheit
((9.0 / 5.0) * inputTemperature) + 32

//Convert Fahrenheit To Celsius
(5.0 / 9.0) * (inputTemperature - 32)
```

It would be even better to make these reusable methods:

```
public static double ConvertCelsiusToFahrenheit(double c)
{
    return ((9.0 / 5.0) * c) + 32;
}

public static double ConvertFahrenheitToCelsius(double f)
{
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);
}
```

Second you also seem to have the logic backwards in your code.  Per your comment following the `if (optCelsius.Checked)` statement:

> If the celsius button is clicked, then the temperature needs to be converted from fahrenheit

This reads as if the Celsius option is checked it should convert from fahrenheit to celsius (you actually do the math of converting fahrenheit to celsius), but your string output is written out as:

> [x] degrees Celsius converts to [y] degrees Fahrenheit.

Which is the opposite of what you have actually done.

#### Other improvements

As for the other things you *could* improve:

You are using `.ToString()` in a weird way.  The parameter for [`double.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) is a string *format*.  What you are trying to do is concatenate strings which you can do in a few different ways:

```
//string concatenation
lblNewTemperature.Text = inputTemperature + " degrees Fahrenheit converts to " + celsius + "degrees Celsius.";

//string.Format
lblNewTemperature.Text = string.Format("{0} degrees Fahrenheit converts to {1} degrees Celsius.", inputTemperature, celsius);

//If you are using C#6 or above you can use string interpolation:
lblNewTemperature.Text = $"{inputTemperature} degrees Fahrenheit converts to {celsius} degrees Celsius.";
```

Next bit of weirdness is your `if` statement logic:

```
if(double.TryParse(txtTemperature.Text, out inputTemperature) == false)
```

is redundant, just check if its not (`!`) true by doing this:

```
if(!double.TryParse(txtTemperature.Text, out inputTemperature))
```

After the `TryParse()` returns a true the rest of your code can now use the `inputTemperature` variable.  So those `double.Parse()` calls you make later can be eliminated.

Next, you should only declare the variables right before they are needed.  From the code you have posted it does not seem like `celsius` and `fahrenheit` are global, and now that we have created conversion methods we can eliminate them completely.

Your final code could be as simple as this (assuming C#6 or higher because of string interpolation):

```
// VARIABLES
double inputTemperature;  // Stores user input

// INPUT
if (!double.TryParse(txtTemperature.Text, out inputTemperature))  // Checking that user input is valid
{
    //textbox did not contain a valid double
}

// PROCESSING
if (optCelsius.Checked)  // If the celsius button is clicked, then the temperature needs to be converted from fahrenheit
{
    lblNewTemperature.Text = $"{inputTemperature} degrees Fahrenheit converts to {ConvertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputTemperature)} degrees Celsius."
}
else if (optFahrenheit.Checked)  // If the fahrenheit button is clicked, then the temperature needs to be converted from celsius
{
    lblNewTemperature.Text = $"{inputTemperature} degrees Celsius converts to {ConvertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputTemperature)} degrees Fahrenheit.";
}
```

Comment: Oh wow... I was waaaaaay off on this one. I cannot thank you enough for your detailed response. My jaw literally dropped. You've made everything a lot clearer, and a lot easier to understand.